# How to replace 2 specific characters with a specific charecter

Tags: java, algorithm, replaceall

I'm trying to change the characters; aa to å,  ae to ä and oe to ö.

My input text file is

"sjoen aer varmt idag
kanske kommer vi att simma daer. Det aer vaeldigt roligt att simma daer.
Min mamma säger till mig att daer aer alltid kallt och att aaka tid tar mycket tid."

The output should be like this:

"sjön är varmt idag
kanske kommer vi att simma där. Det är väldigt roligt att simma där.
Min mamma säger till mig att där är alltid kallt och att åka tid tar mycket tid."

My question is what am I doing wrong?
Thank you for help and comment.

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the file name");



        BufferedReader inputCurrent  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        PrintWriter outputCurrent = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt")));
        String row1;

        while((row1 = inputCurrent.readLine())!=null)
        {
            String aa = "å";
            String ae = "ä";
            String oe = "ö";


            if(row1.equals(aa))
            {
                String replacing  = row1.replaceAll(row1, aa);
                outputCurrent.println(replacing);
            }

            if(row1.equals(ae))
            {
                String replacing  = row1.replaceAll(row1, aa);
                outputCurrent.println(replacing);
            }

            if(row1.equals(oe))
            {
                String replacing  = row1.replaceAll(row1, aa);
                outputCurrent.println(replacing);
            }


        }
        outputCurrent.close();
        inputCurrent.close();


        inputCurrent  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        outputCurrent = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName)));
        while(true)
        {
            String row2 = inputCurrent.readLine();
            if(row2==null)
                break;
            outputCurrent.println(row2);
        }
        outputCurrent.close();
        inputCurrent.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint:  `.equals` ain't gonna cut it if you're looking to replace a sliver of the string.

Comment: Hint 2: The above code replaces _all_ your two-character patterns by å.  You'll never see ä or ö.

Comment: P.S. Don't use the "fix" tag for something you need fixing.  That tag is for something entirely different.  I've removed it.

Comment: Thank you for hints makoto and ajb :)

Comment: Remember that strings are immutable, so row1.replaceAll doesn't change row1, it creates a new String.  Each replaceAll should be done on the result of the previous replaceAll if you want to apply all three changes to the string.

Comment: Do you mean i should use  the Stringbuilder? @HankD

Comment: No, @LenaMonikaMarshall, I mean that if you had the string "aaoeoa", after the first replace, `replacing` will have "åoeoa" and `row1` will still have "aaoeoa".  After the second replace, since `row1` still has "aaoeoa", `replacing` will get "aaoeä" and `row1` will still have "aaoeoa".  After the third replace, since `row1` still has "aaoeoa", `replacing` will get "aaöoa".  Instead you should update `row1` each time, like `row1 = row1.replace(...)` and then you will end up with "åöä"

Comment: Thank you @HankD i watched some videos youtube and i understood better know as you said String is immutable. My wrong was i created a string(String replacing) and i expexted (String replacing) will give to output but i was wrong because every turn row1 would not change itselfs value. THANK YOU SO MUCH  Hank for sharing  those gorgeous knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceAll` takes a pattern as the first argument. You should use `replace`. Also you're looking for `equals` whereas you should do `contains` like this:

```
if(row1.contains("aa"))
    row1.replace("aa", aa);
```

But this way it will replace all the "aa" occurrences to å

See this code:

```
String input = "sjoen aer varmt idag kanske kommer vi att simma daer. "
        + "Det aer vaeldigt roligt att simma daer. "
        + "Min mamma säger till mig att daer aer alltid kallt och att aaka tid tar mycket tid.";
String output = "sjön är varmt idag kanske kommer vi att simma där. "
        + "Det är väldigt roligt att simma där. "
        + "Min mamma säger till mig att där är alltid kallt och att åka tid tar mycket tid.";

input = input.replace("aa", "å").replace("ae", "ä").replace("oe", "ö");

System.out.println(input);
//prints
//sjön är varmt idag kanske kommer vi att simma där. 
//Det är väldigt roligt att simma där. 
//Min mamma säger till mig att där är alltid kallt och att åka tid tar mycket tid.
System.out.println(input.equals(output));//true
```

Comment: Thank you for reply @Johnson. I tried but it doesn't work. I oppened the file to check out  and that is empty.

Comment: Your output has the content  daer aer which did not change to där är. Is this what you want? If so then this is not the way to it. You should do the replacement on a word by word basis.

Comment: You are not accumulating multiple changes.  You do the first substitution, write it out, throw it away, apply the second substitution to the original string, write it out, throw it away, then apply the third substitution to the original string.

Comment: I want to change all aa to å, ae to ä and oe to ö. Which method do i need to use for check out a word by word? (i've tried with for loop and charArt(i)) it did not work.)

Comment: @Hank That was just an illustration of how to use replace. Ofcourse the OP is catching the replaced string.

Comment: Sorry @JohnsonCharles, I meant that as a comment on the original code supplied by the person asking the question.

Comment: @Lena if you want all occurrences to change, then the above code should work. See the output above and let me know if that is not what you want

Comment: Why even bother with `contains`?  It's not necessary.

Comment: @HankD - ah I see. Sorry.

Comment: Your output string to test against is missing the substitutions in daer aer. The goal is for the final output to be true

Comment: @HankD Yep but per OP the output should have daer aer which is what confused me.

Comment: Changed the output string and now the result should match.

Comment: as @HankD wrote when i run eclipse i thought it worked. When i opened the file aaka, aer, daer did not changed. But if i run the same file one more time everythings changed and that become as i want. i'm a begginner and i confused :/ JohnsonCharles

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be effective and better with methods. As i said i'm begginer and appreciate your helps.

```
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the file name");

 BufferedReader inputCurrent  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    PrintWriter outputCurrent = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt")));
    String row1;
    String replacing = null;
    String å,ä,ö;

    while((row1 = inputCurrent.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String aa = "å";
        String ae = "ä";
        String oe = "ö";


        if(row1.contains("aa"))
        {
            row1  = row1.replaceAll("aa", aa);

        }


        if(row1.contains("ae"))                 {
            row1  = row1.replaceAll("ae", ae);

        }

        if(row1.contains("oe"))
        {
            row1  = row1.replaceAll("oe", oe);

        }
        outputCurrent.println(row1);


    }
    outputCurrent.close();
    inputCurrent.close();


    inputCurrent  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    outputCurrent = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName)));
    while(true)
    {
        String row2 = inputCurrent.readLine();
        if(row2==null)
            break;
        outputCurrent.println(row2);
    }
    outputCurrent.close();
    inputCurrent.close();
}
```

}

Comment: This is much better. A suggestion -- as ajb commented, the `if ( row1.contains(...` blocks surrounding your `replaceAll` calls really aren't needed because the `replaceAll` will just return the original string unchanged if it doesn't find any matches.

Comment: @Lena - `replaceAll` method is meant to replace a matching pattern like `"aaabaaaabaababaaaaab".replaceAll("a+", "a")` gives you `"ababababab"`. If you wish to replace just the string then you should use `repalce()` method. It is named poorly but `replace()` and `replaceAll()` both will replace all the occurrences except that the former looks for a matching string while latter looks for a matching pattern.